# Does such a differentiable function exist?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

Does there exists a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f'(0)=0$ and the existence of a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n \to 0$ implies $f(x_n)\to \infty$.

**Attempt**
I guess not, because the derivative is bounded at $x=0$ we can have an open interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ around $x=0$ on which the function is uniformly continuous, and thus also bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $f$ is differentiable at $0$ (note that we do not even need that $f$ is differentiable or even continuous elsewhere), we have that $\lim_x\to 0{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ exists, hence with $\epsilon:=1$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}-f'(0)\right|<1 $$
for $|x|<\delta$. In paticular, $f(x)$ is between two lines with slopes $f'(0)\pm1$ through $(0,f(0))$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, your argumentation allows me to have a more visual idea of the situation!

Answer (score 4):

In order for $f$ to be differentiable in $0$, it has to be continuous in $0$. Therefore $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_{n})=f(0)$$
if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=0$.

Comment: Nice simple solution.